# What is the minimum PHP version required to use the Vimeo PHP API?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

What is the minimum PHP version required to use the [Vimeo](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php) PHP API? I searched in the documentation but couldn't find any hint of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`5.3.0`

Sadly, this is not on the page, but it is in the composer listing [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/composer.json).